# Snapping to grid get's messed up after scaling down vertexes

Tags: modeling, snapping

I've been reading about snapping to grid and hopefully I'm doing it right.

Switching form units to meter measurements and setting the grid scale accordingly. Turning on *Snap during transform* and *Absolute grid alignment*.

Everything seem's to work fine until I scale something down (I'm aware that I have to reset (apply) the scale when resizing my whole model), but the problem seems to come up when I want to work with vertexes.

First I'm selecting, let's say 2 vertexes of my plane, scaling them down and it's okay. But then when I try to scale them up again they are snapping to completely new grid that I somehow created. I don't see any options to reset the scale in *Edit Mode*, also it would be such a pain to do it every time.

Here's a GIF that I recorded, this will help you better understand better what I'm trying to achieve and what I do step by step:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wiXp.gifv

[image]

Comment: The answer is "Push/Pull" tool, see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201663/99751 ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue comes from a misunderstanding of when increment snapping works.

Grid snapping only works for translation operations, scaling and rotation use **value increment snapping** not grid snapping, since rotations and scaling can't always be forced to coincide with the grid without some distortion.

The fact that your first scale does alight with the grid is a coincidence because the starting plane edge was exactly 2 units in length, and the end vertex were both grid aligned to start with.

That resulted in increment snapped values randomly being fractions of 2 units, which matching the grid cells by chance. When scaling up again, the edge will have a random different length, and fractions of that value will no longer necessarily align with the grid.

Bottom line, if you want grid aligned vertex use translations, or manually match them after using other transformation tools.

Comment: So basically when scaling, everything creates kinda like it's own grid and moves by it (in my example, by 10 cm), noticed it while was looking through the changing variables in blender. So from what I understand there's no actual way to have a global alignment grid, what a shame really. Thanks for the answer

Comment: When scaling there are no grids involved at all, it uses a scaling factor, of 0.9>0.7>0.6 etc. Global grid alignments are totally possible, but for translation operations only.

Comment: That's what I meant by grind, the factors you are absolutely correct. But now if you will (because I spent quite some time learning blender for my video game models, and I love this program, don't want to drop it off because of such a stupid thing), how do I model this thing for example: https://i.imgur.com/qIfCsXT.png (30s of MS Paint). For now I'm just duplicating vertexes, moving them around so I get the snapping correctly, and then creating faces between them. Surely this isn't how you do it, we're developers and we're lazy, this involves a lot of clicking. Sorry for my stupidity, ikr

Comment: If you have a different question make a new post, comments are not meant for extended discussions. That sounds simple to do starting from a grid mesh. Also if a question helped you consider upvoting, or marking it as accepted if you feel it solved you problem.