# How to spread/Scale Vertexes by world constant range?

Tags: modeling, scale, snapping

For example i have a tube with 2m diameter, if i select Vertexes of one end, and Scale them using *Snapping* \ *Increment* \ *Absolute Grid Snap*, I get 2.6m diameter on that end, but if I then scale them down, I get 2.08m, because the second scale was in % of 2.6m .

[Snapping to grid get's messed up after scaling down vertexes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107011/snapping-to-grid-gets-messed-up-after-scaling-down-vertexes)

And another related issue, the 10% Scaling steps can't be changed by scaling the model Space (to achieve the steps that you need) .

Does anyone know how to perform such operations, such so the applied value would stay constant to world? (getting 2m after decreasing the diameter)

For example, programmatically the *Absolute Grid Snap* could be achieved by Snapping the closest to grid-step vertex, and range snap by auto/manually selecting a Vertex to translate it's world space modification to the scale space ("%") .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *"push/pull"* to give a distance in world units:

[image]

Comment: Thank you . But p.s., the function misses steps/snapping .

Comment: @irvnriir, are you sure?

Comment: that its not affected by snapping?, yes

Comment: ok, it works for me here in 2.90.1.

Comment: im on 2.90.1 . https://gofile.io/d/Gzxpn2

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm used to hold ctrl or ctrl/shift keys and it works. But effectively not when snapping is just on, you're right.

Comment: You are right too, LMB+ctrl+shift for 0.1 units . Another thanks .